# What is the best place to fire an event in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

It's actually a general question not necessarily related to the Laravel.

I'm thinking between a Controller and a Repository. Or maybe there is a better place? What are pros and cons? What are your thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment is about nothing. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to use events between controllers and repository. This makes your repository tightly coupled to your app.

Instead just fire your events inside your controllers and in your event handlers you address your repository and other business logic units. This way you don't have to declare any event listeners/handlers inside your (or any) repositories.

**EDIT**

Events are meant to be used as stateless processes.

> Stateless means there is no record of previous interactions and each interaction request has to be handled based entirely on information that comes with it - [source](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless)

So the best practice is that you fire your events inside you controllers, but only if you don't expect any call back from the endpoint.(if so you interact with the desired repository in side your controller).

**Example** after handling user registration inside your controller (where you address one or many or none repositories) you fire event *UserRegistered*. Now inside your handler, you receive user object, and with the information inside, you send an email with a welcome message. Again you can use none, one or many libraries inside your handler. You can even fire another event, but you cannot pass any info back to the point where the event was launched from.

Now some libraries have internal 'buses' where you can hook up to and listen for information. You can use those for domain events and create your own listeners. You can also replicate this scenario inside your own libraries if you want to have hooks for other devs (of your self outside your lib)

Comment: That makes sense. But in some cases I don't see other possibilities. For example, From controller I call a method of a repo . The method iterates through a Collection of Models and, by some condition, changes the state of the Model and fires an event ModelUpdatedEvent. Does it mean that the architecture is wrong? Or what would you do it such situation?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? Your opinion is to fire events in Controllers only?

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your use case. You can fire event from controller or model/repository.

Based on your question, I describe two scenario :

1. **Event based on user actions:**

   If your event is related to user action. You can fire it from your controller.

   **Example:**

   Lets say you are building an logistic management project. You can fire an `OrderShipped` event after order is shipped.

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\Order;
   use App\Events\OrderShipped;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

   class OrderController extends Controller
   {
        /**
        * Ship the given order.
        *
        * @param  int  $orderId
        * @return Response
        */
        public function ship($orderId)
        {
            $order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);

            // Order shipment logic...

            event(new OrderShipped($order));
        }
   }
   ```
2. **Event based on your code actions:**

   If you have action in your code. You can fire the event from there.

   **Example:**

   Laravel itself fire an event for saving, updating in their models. Have a look at code events [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L495).

**Edit:**

So don't look for a place to fire an event. Look for action, use case and scenario to fire an event. Usually events increase the re-usability of your code.

Comment: I know that I can fire an event from any place. I'm looking for good reasons, for pros and cons for a specific place.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, Don't go after place to fire it. Go after use cases and actions. It will give you good architecture. But make sure it won't go in infinite loop.